# How to get Annotation of PsiType?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

I'm trying to implement a custom lint check, that should report calls to a given function, if the function parameter type is not annotated with a specific annotation.

```
@MyAnnotation
class ClassA {
    void memberMethod() {
        SomeUtil.someMethod(this); // first call
    }
}

class ClassB {
    void memberMethod() {
        SomeUtil.someMethod(this); // second call
    }
}
```

I want lint to report the second call, but not the first.

I managed to get the parameter expression reported. But lint reports both calls and I don't know why...

```
public class MyDetector extends Detector implements Detector.JavaPsiScanner {
    private static final Class<? extends Detector> DETECTOR_CLASS = MyDetector.class;
    private static final EnumSet<Scope> DETECTOR_SCOPE = Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE;

    private static final Implementation IMPLEMENTATION = new Implementation(
        DETECTOR_CLASS,
        DETECTOR_SCOPE
    );

    private static final String ISSUE_ID = "MyId";
    private static final String ISSUE_DESCRIPTION = "Some short description.";
    private static final String ISSUE_EXPLANATION = "Some long description.";
    private static final Category ISSUE_CATEGORY = Category.CORRECTNESS;
    private static final int ISSUE_PRIORITY = 7;
    private static final Severity ISSUE_SEVERITY = Severity.WARNING;

    public static final Issue ISSUE = Issue.create(
        ISSUE_ID,
        ISSUE_DESCRIPTION,
        ISSUE_EXPLANATION,
        ISSUE_CATEGORY,
        ISSUE_PRIORITY,
        ISSUE_SEVERITY,
        IMPLEMENTATION
    );

    public MyDetector() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(Context context, File file) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<Scope> getApplicableFiles() {
        return Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getApplicableMethodNames() {
        return Collections.singletonList("someMethod");
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethod(JavaContext context, JavaElementVisitor visitor, PsiMethodCallExpression call, PsiMethod method) {
        for (PsiExpression psi : call.getArgumentList().getExpressions()) {
            PsiType type = psi.getType();
            if (type != null) {
                for (PsiAnnotation anno : type.getAnnotations()) { // type.getAnnotations() is always empty
                    if (MyAnnotation.class.getName().equals(anno.getQualifiedName())) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                context.report(ISSUE, context.getLocation(psi), ISSUE.getBriefDescription(TextFormat.TEXT));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here but I have troubles finding some good Psi documentation...

Answer (score 1):

After some deep research I finally got it to work.
I had to transform the PsiType to a PsiClass and read the annotations from there.